# Determine if modal dialog is open for specific unit - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have an application in Delphi 7, which pops up modal dialogs for several conditions. I am trying to determine if the dialog from a specific unit is open from another unit and close it. So far, I've tried with following code:

```
Wnd := GetLastActivePopup(Application.Handle);
if (Wnd <> 0) and (Wnd <> Application.Handle) then
   PostMessage(Wnd, wm_close,0,0);
```

But, it closes all the opened dialogs. When I tried to specify for a specific form such as:

```
if (Wnd <> 0) and (Wnd <> FormTest.Handle) then
```

it throws Access Violation error.

How can I determine whether the dialog from specific unit is being popped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution that may work.

You could use:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  h: hwnd;
begin
  h := FindWindow(PChar('TForm1'), PChar('Form1'));
  if h <> 0 then  
    PostMessage(h, WM_CLOSE, 0,0);
end;
```

It works well to identify if the there is a handle to the TForm1 window. The obvious thing here is that `FindWindow` will seek windows in the entire OS system. Now, if you want something faster, you could use @Remy solution, that will only seek for Application's forms.

From MSDN:

> **FindWindow function:**
>
> Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window
> name match the specified strings. This function does not search child
> windows. This function does not perform a case-sensitive search.

To Search for child windows use the following function:

> **FindWindowEx function:**
>
> Retrieves a handle to a window whose class name and window name match
> the specified strings. The function searches child windows, beginning
> with the one following the specified child window. This function does
> not perform a case-sensitive search.

These are links to the both functions, respectively: [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh my, this is surely not the solution to any problem!

Comment: Then I think they should to remove `findwindow` from WinApi

Comment: No, I mispoke. I meant this is not the solution to this problem. Even so, you'd normally use `EnumWindows` to get all top level windows rather than `FindWindow` to get the first. In any case, a desktop wide solution is surely not what was requested here.

Comment: this is pointed out in my answer : "The obvious thing here is that FindWindow will seek windows in the entire OS system." that's also why I suggested @Remy's answer

Comment: Sure. I never understand why people accept answers that don't address the question that they asked.

Comment: I believe that in this situation, it's because with `findwindow`, OP don't need to iterate between all Screen.Forms, leading to write less code

Comment: I believe right or wrong is a matter of perspective, if this solve the problem, why, I ask you, it would be wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't bother if I were you. If the asker wants to accept this answer, then that's their choice. You did point out the flaw in the answer. Anyone reading carefully would realise the peril of running this code when you have multiple instances of the app running.

Comment: No problem will happen, i think findwindow is somehow optimized to seek firstly in the same thread and same process, all test's that I did, the OS closed the right form. Obviously, this is a guess, I don't have any documentation to prove it

Answer (score 5):

Try looping through the `Screen.Forms` list looking for the desired modal form, and if found then close it:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  Frm: TForm;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
  begin
    Frm := Screen.Forms[I];
    if fsModal in Frm.FormState then
    begin
      if Frm is TDesiredFormClass then
      // or: if Frm.ClassName = 'TDesiredFormClass' then
      // or: GetTypeData(PTypeInfo(Frm.ClassInfo))^.UnitName = 'DesiredUnitName' then
      // or: if (whatever other criteria you need) then
      begin
        Frm.Close; // sets ModalResult to mrCancel
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Wnd <> 0) and (Wnd <> FormTest.Handle) then
```

This leads to access violation if FormTest is not a valid instance reference. Either:

1. FormTest is nil, or
2. FormTest is not-nil, but refers to an object that has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the classname of the window with [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx) function